# How to make arduino show cpu usage with 10 leds?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, cpu-usage, led

So i want to make arduino show my computer cpu usage with leds, for example if 10% then 1 led will light, if 50% then 5 leds, if 80% then 8 leds...
I am using windows 8.1 pro

Comment: Tell us the steps you need to take to accomplish the task.

Comment: I need to Get the CPU usage of my computer and then communicate that to the Arduino and have the Arduino respond to the data but im new at arduino so i need help, i dont even know how to get cpu usage for arduino :s

Answer (score 0):

1. A computer program sends the current CPU usage over serial to the arduino
2. The arduino interprets the serial messages and displays the percentage via the leds

Answer (score 0):

You can find a simple example here: http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/basic-effects/vu-meter/

```
void setup() {
    for (uint8_t pin=2; pin<20; ++pin) {
        pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);  
    }
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("ready, send characters a-s to control output");
    set_volume(0);
}

void set_volume(uint8_t volume) {
    volume+= 2;
    for (uint8_t pin=2; pin<20; ++pin) {
        digitalWrite(pin, pin<volume);
    }
}

void loop() {
    uint8_t volume = Serial.read() - 'a';
    if (volume < 't'-'a') {
        set_volume(volume);
    }
}
```

This code was intended as a VU display but it will work just as well as a CPU load display. You only need to push the CPU load values to the Arduino. You should have told us your operating system.